# Crear nuevo logger en Wildfly 10 utilizando log4j

Tags: java, xml, wildfly, log4j

Necesito **loggear** ciertos módulos en una *app* en un log **diferente a server.log**, inicialmente lo intente hacer con un proyecto java y su archivo *log4j2.xml* el cual funciona muy bien en otro servidor de aplicaciones diferente a *wildfly* como *weblogic.*

Leyendo y buscando en google encontre que hay que *crear el logger* en el subsistema   **"logging:3.0"**. A pesar de que lo hago tal cual veo en los foros, aun no me funciona..

El perfil que utiliza mi **wildfly** es *"standalone-full.xml"*
y el **código xml** es el siguiente:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="PRUEBA_TRACE">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN-PRUEBA"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="PRUEBA/TRACE/trace.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>


        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

        <!--LOGGER-->
        <logger category="co.com.powersoft.learningenglish" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="PRUEBA_TRACE"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>

        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>

        <!--FORMATTER-->
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>

        <formatter name="PATTERN-PRUEBA">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>

    </subsystem>
```

Alguien sabe que en dónde esta el error?
Espero me puedan ayudar, Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Yo estoy usando **EAP 7.0**  y tengo la siguiente configuración de **log4j:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC
  "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">

<!-- Configuración de log4j -->
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}; [%t]; %-5p; %c; %x - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="./target/pagos-logger.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}; [%t]; %-5p; %c; %x - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.wpattern.frameworks">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>


<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.jboss">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="all" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: En realidad lo que necesito es poner a loggear en un archivo diferente a server.log.. Por ende necesito crear una configuración para un nuevo log. Ya modifique la pregunta para ser mas especifico.. Gracias..

Comment: `<appender name="file" 
   class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
     <param name="File" value="./target/pagos-logger.log" />
     <param name="Append" value="true" />
     <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}; [%t]; %-5p; %c; %x - 
   %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>`

Debes agregar esa linea y cambiar el value por la ubicacion del archivo, este file creo que debe existir

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la pregunta es vieja, puedo afirmar que usar log4j en una aplicación java funciona muy bien en wildfly 10..no hay necesidad de crear un nuevo logging en el subsistema de logs.

En mi proyecto en la carpeta resources puse un fichero log4j2.xml con este contenido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">/home/wildfly/wildfly_logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/correspondencia-service.log"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/service-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```